# Pass data from one form to another (datagridview)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm working on some easy log implementation. I've created some datagridview in Changelog.cs that has columns: user's ID, surname, action name ("authorization", for example), time.

(ex: 16, Brown, authorization, 10:30:00)

So I've got 2 forms: **Authorization** and **Changelog**

When user presses the button 'sign in' in Authorization form, I want to insert this data to datagridview in Changelog.
In Changelog I've got this constructor:

```
public Changelog(string id, string user, string operation, string date)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = id;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = user;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = operation;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = date;
    }
```

And in Authorization I've got this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime whenClicked = DateTime.Now;
        // long authorization code
    }
```

Doing in Authorization:

```
Changelog cl = new Changelog(currentUser.Id.ToString(), currentUser.Name, "authorization", whenClicked.ToString())
```

of course creates a new instance of Changelog, but I want to insert this data to the *original one*

Is there any way to implement this? Thank you!

Comment: Retrieve the current existing instance of your form from Application.OpenForms. And if you need to pass new information to the existing instance you will need a public method on the ChangeLog form that receives the new data and insert into the DataGridView

Comment: So, the changelog is volatile? If you close the app and open it again, it's empty? (or better "should" be?)

Comment: ^^ What I'm going for is: If I had to do this, I'd simply write an actual log through a logging framework like Serilog. Most of the widely used ones offer sinks (or targets or whatever they call it) to populate Windows Forms Controls, e.g.: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.WinForms. That adds the benefit that you could easily write those to file, database, ... for nearly 0 additional (code writing) cost, just by adding more sinks in configuration.

Comment: Do you happen to use some form of Dependency Injection? If so, there would also be other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the existin instance of a Form looking at the [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0) property, then use the instance present in that collection to send the new information.
But to do this you need some changes both in Changelog and Authorization.
First remove the parameters passed to Changelog constructor and create a new method that add the info to the DataGridView. So you can call this method independently from the form creation.

```
public Changelog()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void AddNewLog(string id, string user, string operation, string date)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = id;
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = user;
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = operation;
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = date;
}
```

Now in Authorization search for the existing Changelog instance and use that instance and the AddNewLog method to add the information. Of course, if the Changelog instance is not present you can create it as before (but without passing the parameters).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime whenClicked = DateTime.Now;
    // long authorization code 

    Changelog cl = Application.OpenForms["Changelog"] as Changelog;
    if(cl == null)
        cl = new Changelog();
    cl.AddNewLog(currentUser.Id.ToString(), currentUser.Name, "authorization", whenClicked.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to do this after you posted the first comment. But cl is always null (I have no idea why), so it creates a new Changelog and I get the same thing - it doesn't insert data in original instance

Comment: Did you copy and paste? Mind that "Changelog" != "ChangeLog"

Comment: @Fildor wow, really?! Of course I wrote it myself -_- and how do you think it would run if the name of the form was wrong? lol

Comment: @ElizabethGrant `Application.OpenForms["ChangeLog"]` will return _what_ if your actual class is `Changelog`? _"Of course I wrote it myself"_ - you won't believe how many times we've seen similar errors just because of c&p.

Comment: @Fildor emm, did you see 'as Changelog' or 'Changelog cl'? If I c&p there would be a mistake that it can't find such namespace 'ChangeLog.'

Comment: I was talking about the string inside "[]" of `Application.OpenForms["ChangeLog"]`. Is there a typo? (btw I'd recommend to use `nameof(Changelog)`)

Comment: @Fildor No, I wrote everything correctly, that is ["Changelog"].

Comment: Hmm, ok. And it's null, you say. I am assuming the Form had been created and could be expected to be non-null... that's weird.

Comment: @Fildor  that's why I wrote a comment to Steve. Debugger displays that it's null, like always. btw, every form I tried to find with OpenForms returns null.

Comment: OK, just to be on the same page (correct if wrong): 1. You clicked "sign in" => cl is null, thus created, which is fine. 2. You clicked "sign in" again, again cl turns out null. And you didn't close, minimize or do anything to or with Changelog Window in between, right?

Comment: _"btw, every form I tried to find with OpenForms returns null."_ - oh, wow. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67569372/edit) and add the new code to your question?

Comment: @Fildor nope. don't do anything in between. moreover, I've created a new form (because I've read about some bug with OpenForms) and still returns 0.

Comment: Hm, ... Give me some time. I'll try and write up an alternative you can try.

Comment: @Fildor no, you don't have to. I think it's just me. But still got no idea how it can actually be like that

Comment: OK, fixed the L typo. This should work now. Unless between the first click and second click there is a close/dispose of the Changelog instance

Answer (score 0):

Since Steve's answer doesn't seem to be working (quite to my surprise), maybe this will help you: The basic idea is using events, and static events at that.

So, in your `Authorization` Form, you'd declare an event like this:

```
public static event EventHandler<ActionLogEventArgs> AuthorizationEvent;
// ^^ `ActionLogEventArgs` are `EventArgs` + your id, user, operation ... props

// Trigger function
protected virtual void OnAuthorization( ActionLogEventArgs args )
{
    var handler = AuthorizationEvent;
    handler?.Invoke(null, args);
}
```

So, whenever "sign-in" is clicked, you build your `ActionLogEventArgs` and fire the event by calling `OnAuthorization(args)`

In your "Changelog" Form you register a handler for that event:

```
// in ctor:
Authorization.AuthorizationEvent += AddLog;
// ...

private void AddLog(object sender, ActionLogEventArgs e)
{
    // Add to your DataGrid; make sure this executes on UI Thread.
}
```

Mind that I chose to use a static event to avoid having to have an instance.
I'd usually prefer non-static events but that would require some more effort.

Let's see if this could work for you, first.

---

### On DataGridView

What also came to my mind was:

You might want to actually [*insert*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.insert?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRowCollection_Insert_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRow_) a new Row.

`grid.Rows[0].Cells[x].Value = ...` will *change* that row, not insert a new one.